# How to put multiple numbers into string regardless of the number for String.format

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I want to create a sentence inserting some numbers like "Your tag numbers are 1, 2, 3"
The number of the numbers varies depending on the input like (1,2,3) or (1,2,3,4). How can it be flexible in order to create the sentece regardless of the variable number of numbers? I thought using String.format and String.join resolves this issue, but I'm hitting the wall. So I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

```
    //input example 1
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    //input example 2
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3,4);
    String.format("Your tag numbers are %s",
    String.join(",", Lists.transform(numbers, Functions.toStringFunction())));
```

Comment: What's the actual problem with your approach - incorrect result, compilation error, something else? Where does `Lists.transform` and `Functions.toStringFunction` come from?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(",")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `List.toString` function:

```java
List<Integer> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3,4);
String s = numbers1.toString(); //"[1, 2, 3, 4]"
s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1); //"1, 2, 3, 4"  
System.out.println(s);
```

> 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex you can eliminate the unwanted characters from the `toString()` output of List.

- `[\\[\\]]` character class. Precede the brackets with `\\` since `[]` are regex special characters and must be escaped.

```
List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3,4);

String regex = "[\\[\\]]";
System.out.printf("Your tag numbers are %s.%n", numbers1.toString().replaceAll(regex,""));
System.out.printf("Your tag numbers are %s.%n", numbers2.toString().replaceAll(regex,""));
```

prints

```
Your tag numbers are 1, 2, 3. 
Your tag numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4.
```